# Fresh react native app is throwing an error with android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

[image: Error]

I've made a new React Native project using npx react-native init AwesomeProject.  This is the error I'm getting and I can't find out why.  Any suggestions? Mind you this is a brand new project.  I execute the new command and then tried to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the error "EONENT: no such file or directory" restart your computer and rebuild your application.  This resolved my issue.  Stupid, yes I know